# Div appears on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which applies class which shows/hide a div.

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
      function reusuableUpAnimFunc(elementName, offset, hideClass, showClass) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
        $animation = $(elementName);                
          ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $animation.removeClass(hideClass).addClass(showClass):
            $animation.addClass(hideClass).removeClass(showClass);
        });
      } 

reusuableUpAnimFunc('#top-btn', 400, 'element-hide', 'element-show');
});
```

css

```
.element-hide {
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.element-show {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

Problem is when the page first loads the div is visible, then as soon as user scrolls it disappears, then reappears as it's supposed to. I want it to be opacity 0 until the offset distance is reached

Comment: Maybe use `display: none` until the scroll is triggered?

Comment: because it calls when page document is ready. by default you should add hide code when page loads

Comment: just write in CSS `#top-btn { opacity:0;visibility:hidden }` . Not sure why you use both opacity and visibility :)

Comment: You're right, I missed that part. Thanks. I use both cause I want it completely gone (it overlays other divs)

Comment: then why don't you use `display:none/block` ? keep in mind that `visiblity` and `display` can not be animated. Opacity can

Comment: @MihaiT, the downside of `display:none` is that it reflows the content as if the element is not there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger the scroll callback function on page load with [`triggerHandler('scroll')`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/). I would write it as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    function swapClass(selector, class1, class2, setClass2) {
        $(selector).toggleClass(class1, !setClass2).toggleClass(class2, setClass2);
    }

    function reusuableUpAnimFunc(selector, offset, hideClass, showClass) {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            swapClass(selector, hideClass, showClass, $(this).scrollTop() > offset);
        }).triggerHandler('scroll');
    }

    reusuableUpAnimFunc('#top-btn', 50, 'element-hide', 'element-show');
});
```

```css
.element-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.element-show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
p { height: 50px };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>scroll down...<p>
<div id="top-btn">This will appear on scrolling</div>
<p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
```

Or, you could just call the function explicitly:

```
    // ...
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        swapClass(selector, hideClass, showClass, $(this).scrollTop() > offset);
    });
    // Call it now:
    swapClass(selector, hideClass, showClass, $(this).scrollTop() > offset);
    // ...
```